# Another modal popup extender question

Tags: c#, asp.net, modalpopupextender

I am trying to get a modal popup to work, it needs to be triggered in the Code behind.

```
 <asp:Button ID="btnModalPopUp" runat="server" Text="Button" Style="display: none" />
<asp:Panel ID="pnlModalPopup" runat="server" CssClass="modalPopup" Style="display: none"
    Width="233px">
    <div id="Div1" runat="server" cssclass="title">
        Modal text here.
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtEditComments" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
</asp:Panel>
<cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="modalMessage" runat="server" TargetControlID="btnModalPopUp"
    PopupControlID="pnlModalPopup" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground"         DropShadow="true"/>
```

Code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    modalMessage.Show();
}
```

Even though it hits the "modalMessage.Show();" code it doesn't show the modal panel.

Comment: OK - what is the Problem? BTW: <asp:Panel ... Style="display: none" - "display:none" is not required.

Comment: @Arthur: `display:none` is cosmetically needed, otherwise the popup will display when the page is loading, then will quickly disappear while the `ModalPopupExtender` kicks in and hides it.

Comment: Just a question, but does this work if you remove "display:none" from btnModalPopup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two solutions:

**The first solution:**

Remove `Style="display:none"` from the `pnlModalPopup`.

The first solution is will cause the popup to "flash" on the screen when the page first loads, and then quickly disappear.

**The second solution:**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pnlModalPopup.Style["display"] = "block";
    modalMessage.Show();
}
```

**Recommendation:**
I would recommend using the second solution, that way the modal popup doesn't flicker and then disappear.

## Edit:  I just tested your code:

I just tested your code in a simple page that contained only the code that you provided...**It worked like expected**.

Check the following:

1. Is your modal popup is defined in an `UpdatePanel` that is conditionally updated?
2. Check to make sure that the modal popup isn't defined in a `Panel` that has it's visibility set to false.
3. If that doesn't work, then check if the modal popup is actually in the source code of the rendered web page.

Comment: Are there any other references in your code where you set the visibility of the `pnlModalPopup` (Either through the style tag, or the visible property)?

Comment: CSS:
.modalBackground {
    background-color:Gray;
    filter:alpha(opacity=70);
    opacity:0.7;  
}
.modalPopup{
    background-color:#ffffff;
    padding:3px;
}

This is the only styling I do with those controls.

Comment: I to can get it to work in a standard aspx page with no masterpages or extra stuff.
To answer your questions:
1. No, it isn't in a update panel.
2. No, it is not in another panel that is hidden, it is however in a masterpage.
3. Yes, it seems to be all there in the source code.

Comment: @Adam: Is the Page_Load you are using in the master page or the specific page of concern?

Comment: I just added the `modalMessage` to a `Master` page in my test app, and it still works fine.  I would try and track down and evaluate all references to `modalMessage` and `pnlModalPopup`

Comment: Also, what css are you using for the "title" class?

Comment: Another thought, is your logic for hiding the modalMessage being triggered and executed somehow?

Comment: Still couldn't get it to 100%. Not sure what the problem was. Thanks everyone for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Listen to Chris's comment as it is needed:

> display:none is cosmetically needed,
>   otherwise the popup will display when
>   the page is loading, then will quickly
>   disappear while the ModalPopupExtender
>   kicks in and hides it.

We had to make ours show like this:

```
  pnlModalPopup.Visible = true;           
  modalMessage.Show();
```

Comment: that would only work if they were setting the Visible property to false somewhere in the code behind, because he isn't setting the Visible property in the markup.  And if that were the case...he should consider **never setting the `Visible` property in the first place.**

Comment: We don't set the visible property in ours, test it out.

Comment: If the modal doesn't display, there is more than likely a JavaScript error.

Comment: If you put a break point there, you will see that `pnlModalPopup.Visible` is true before you set it to true.  The statement is redundant and unnecessary *unless* you've set the `Visible` property to false before hand.

Comment: I don't disagree with you, sometimes people don't come clean with their explanations.  If it doesn't work while being explicit, he has other issues.